# How to make solid hair for girl (not strand by strand)

Tags: modeling

[image]
How can I make the hair as such? It is not strand by strand as I've seen from tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is one or a couple of meshes, so it is mainly matter of picking the proper path rather than choosing a specific tool.
A way to approach would be sculpting indeed, if you prefer modeling it then create a rough mesh which will follow roughly the shape of the head, then extrude few faces to make this spiky ends of the strands and apply a subdivision modifier.
There must be plenty of examples out there, try the combination of keywords "sculpting hair mesh" either on google or youtube.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a hair particle system you need to model hair as a mesh.

Here are two tutorials that go into the details of this kind of workflow:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2XjdzzWCqI
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo_FxdSe_F8

In a nutshell:

- You need to model the hair as a mesh, just like the head and and other solid object.
- Non-destructive editing (via modifiers) would save a lot of time and give some flexibility make changes later.
- In 1st video I have shared a fairly classic method of hair modelling is described; a curve to determine the flow of hair and another curve to serve as profile.  I think working on a single clump of hair (as described there) is a great start.

---

Also you can check out this tutorial for making a stylistic hair material: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxWWBmIUxbc